# Source for an Al-Kindi quotation

Tags: reference-request, truth, quote

Can anyone provide me with a reliable source for the quote below which is attributed to Al-Kindi, preferably from his own work?

> It is fitting for us not to be ashamed to acknowledge truth and to assimilate it from whatever source it comes to us. For him who scales the truth there is nothing of higher value than truth itself it never cheapens nor abases him.

Comment: What is the context of this quotation? Why would there be any shame involved in the first place?

Comment: It was mentioned in the conclusion to Jim Al-Khalili's series "Science and Islam". The shame could come from admitting, as a Muslim, that are factual, specifically scientific, inaccuracies or omissions in the Qur'an.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Al-Kindi](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/al-kindi/)'s [On First Philosoph](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZDgfs_jUhYUC&pg=PA58), Engl.transl., page 58.